# How to create popup window from json schema?

Tags: python, popupwindow, jsonschema

Actually am stuck in my project. I need to generate a popup window from JSON schema and according to the schema only I need to take input from the user.
this is my schema:

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{ 
        "APPLICATION":{"type":"string","enum":["MUL"]},
        "CAR_TYPE":{"type":"string"},
        "VER":{"type":"number"}
     }
}
```

and I need output like:

In the popup window, if the user enters "APPLICATION field other than "MUL" then it won't allow the user to proceed further.

Comment: Please be more clearer in explaining what your issue is. And post the code which you have tried till now.

Comment: I need to write a python code in such a way that according to jsonschema only user are allowed to enter data in the popup window.I generated popup window using python 'TKinter'.